# macOS App CPU usage is inconsistent with Activity Monitor's User CPU Usage

Tags: xcode, macos

According to Xcode, my app is using up about 23% of CPU:

[image]

This seems consistent with its CPU usage indicated by Activity Monitor:

[image]

Now if you look at the bottom section of the Activity Monitor screenshot, you'll see it's indicating about 5% *User* CPU usage, i.e. ["The percentage of CPU capability that’s being used by apps you opened, or by the processes opened by those apps."](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/activity-monitor/actmntr43452/mac)

This looks incoherent. If the app is taking up 23% CPU, why is User CPU usage 5%?

Comment: seems like a bug in the activity monitor.

Comment: No, this regularly occurs with any app. In fact, if you open your Activity Monitor right now you'll see that the sum of all your apps' CPU usage is much higher than the User CPU usage reading.

Comment: yeap, saw that. so my guesses are;
1. design flaw (because of the multi-core calculations)
2. again, could be a bug.

I'd still go with the the second one since there's no inconsistency with htop

Comment: now i believe both are possbile because activity monitor doesn't show the correct cpu usage in the grand sum.

* sysctl -n vm.loadavg                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ─╯
{ 3.87 3.39 4.06 }

* activity monitor says cpu is idle for %80 while the load and htop are increasing.

I believe xcode shows the resource usage correctly. use (sudo) htop for realtime statistics with more details.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean when a %CPU exceeds (# of cores) x 100%?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/what-does-it-mean-when-a-cpu-exceeds-of-cores-x-100)

Comment: @Willeke activity monitor cannot correctly calculate the multi-core/thread utilization; that's the issue. I still believe that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

An Apple Developer Tools Engineer [answered my question in the Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710931), I'm reposting below:

> An app's CPU usage is measured in terms of "how much of a single CPU core does it use?". That's why the CPU usage of a process in this view can also go above 100%. E.g. 300% CPU usage would mean the process uses as much CPU cycles as 3 CPUs can provide (it might still be running on 6 CPUs for 50% each).
>
> However, the split in System, User and Idle is measured in terms of total CPU cycles the system can provide. You can also see this difference in the Xcode view: The left-most number on the gauge is 1200, indicating that the maximum CPU usage you can have is 1200%. This indicates that the system you are measuring has 12 CPU cores available.
>
> You can now take the 23% of a single CPU the app uses and divide it by 12 to arrive at the share of the system's CPUs the app uses: 23%/12 = 1.9%, which fits into the 5.13% of user CPU usage you see.